# Android displaying items on screen on that come from a remote db

Tags: android

I am facing an issue of having a screen which gets an id from the SharedPreferences and then I call a remote database, and then I have to display that data on the screen.

Is it possible to do that with ViewText or is there another way to place text on the screen after a remote db call is made?

Whats the best way to do that and how do I accomplish it?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The logic would that I would use is to build your screen in XML and have a Textview named myTextView

in your activity declare a Textview

```
TextView name_field;

String name;
....
.
.
.

//call my database info 
//this example get a variable and pass it into String variable name and then display it in your text view

name_field = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myTextView);
name_field.setText(name);
```

Comment: You fail to mention that doing this in the normal way will completely block the UI thread. Tyler Treat's response solves this issue by executing asynchronously in an AsyncTask. Have a look at the specs [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) because this is exactly the kind of thing that it is meant for.

Comment: I made no assumptions whatsoever about whether this is done on the main thread or in a Async task or wherever. My answer dealt with the issue of updating a text field and nothing else..

Answer (score 2):

Use a loader for your db call. Once the data has loaded use onLoadFinished to either add a TextView to your layout or replace the text in an existing layout. 
My suggestion would be to create a TextView in your layout in xml so that you can position it exactly as you wish, then replacing the text after your database call using myTextView.setText(databasetext)

Answer (score 2):

The way you display data from a database is completely independent of the way you're getting that data. If it's simply text you need to display, then a `TextView` seems to be a logical view element to use.

In simple terms, the steps you should be taking would likely be:

1. Get ID from `SharedPreferences`
2. Query database with ID for result
3. Pass the result to your view layer
4. Use a `TextView` to display the result

It's best (and required since 4.0) to make network calls in a thread separate from the UI thread. The best way is probably using an `AsyncTask`. For example:

```
private class GetDbItemTask extends AsyncTask<Integer, Void, MyDbItem> {

    protected MyDbItem doInBackground(Integer... ids) {
        return mDbService.load(ids[0]);
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(MyDbItem result) {
        mTextView.setText(result.toString());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a custom alert dialog [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlertDialog.html)?

This allows you to have a textview on your screen without changing your activity.

I hope I answered this correctly since you ask

> "Is it possible to do that with ViewText or is there another way to
>   place text on the screen after a remote db call is made?".

Then there is the option of refreshing the screen using onResume() on the activity lifecycle.